# How can I disable java applets with PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I'm trying to manipulate a web page in PhantomJS, and I can't disable the Java applets in it.

Is there any command or something else that I can use?

Comment: "Join into" ? This is a browser issue, not coding. If you want to disable Java you can always disable the browser java plugin.

Comment: I wrote wrong sorry, Im trying to just join .

Comment: join what ? visit a webpage ?

Comment: Yes, I want to entry in a webpage with phantomjs , but I cant because there is a java applet. How can I disable this applet?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a setting in PhantonJS to stop it from running Java code, but you could use DOM to remove the applets from the page like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script>
      function disableApplets(){
        var applets = document.querySelectorAll("applet")
        for(var i = 0; i < applets.length; ++i){
          applets[i].parentNode.removeChild(applets[i])
        }
      }
      addEventListener("load", function(){
        var button = document.querySelector("#disable")
        button.addEventListener("click", disableApplets)
      })
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <applet code="Bubbles.class" width="350" height="350">
    Java applet that draws animated bubbles.
    </applet>
    <button id="disable">Disable applets</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `--load-plugins=false` flag.

http://www.ryanbridges.org/2013/05/21/putting-the-flash-back-in-phantomjs/

However this should be off already by default.